# What is the difference between the Garbage-Collection Mechanism in PyQT5 programs and normal conditions? (If this is a GC-related problem)

Tags: python, oop, pyqt5, garbage-collection, class-attributes

To learn about the **Object-Deletion Features** of metaclass **QObject** in PyQT5, I wrote the following code:

```py
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setup_UI()
        self.setup_subUI()
        self.hook = None

    def setup_UI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('MyWindowTitle')
        self.resize(600, 400)

    def setup_subUI(self):
        obj1 = QObject()
        obj2 = QObject(obj1)
        obj3 = QObject(obj2)
        self.hook = obj1  # This is line 19.
        obj1.setObjectName('obj1')
        obj2.setObjectName('obj2')
        obj3.setObjectName('obj3')
        obj1.destroyed.connect(lambda obj: print(f'Object {obj.objectName()} has been released'))
        obj2.destroyed.connect(lambda obj: print(f'Object {obj.objectName()} has been released'))
        obj3.destroyed.connect(lambda obj: print(f'Object {obj.objectName()} has been released'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

There are several obvious facts in the code above:

1. The `Window` class has an non-essential attribute, `hook`, that was originally used to bind to `obj1`;
2. `obj1` is the parent object of `obj2`, `obj2` is the parent object of `obj3`. If no objects are involved in *Reference Counting*, all three of them will be quickly recovered to activate the `destroyed` signal receiver below as well as print this message further.

To avoid GC, I added line 19 to try to keep them, `self.hook = obj1`, but it backfired.

##### *Here's the puzzle:*

If line 19 is changed to `self.other_attribute_not_schedule = obj1`, the program will not release these 3 objects before the Window UI entity is closed.
More clearly, **could you please tell me more details about the objects get deleted with the above code, and why they don't when I use the other line?**

Comment: What are you asking exactly? Do you want to know why the objects get deleted with the above code, or why they don't when you use the other line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Garbage collection activates when the number of references of an object reaches 0. In that case, python tries to delete it, if Qt allows it.

In your original code you first of all call `setup_subUI`, which creates a reference:

```
self.hook = obj1
```

Then, *after* `setup_subUI` returns, you do the following:

```
self.hook = None
```

This results in "overwriting" `self.hook` as a reference to `None`, so the previous reference (`obj1`) is removed. Since that was the *only* reference, it gets deleted, along with its children.

Then you do the following instead, again in `setup_subUI`:

```
self.other_attribute_not_schedule = obj1
```

When `setup_subUI` returns, the next line will be evaluated as above:

```
self.hook = None
```

The difference here is that you're not overwriting `self.hook` since it didn't exist yet, and the `obj1` is not deleted, because its reference (`self.other_attribute_not_schedule`) still exists.

Note there are different types of references (for instance, adding an object to a persistent list) and they might not always be explicit, especially with complex modules like Qt.

For instance, adding the parent to the constructor of the first object will prevent deletion, even if you do `self.hook = None`:

```
obj1 = QObject(self)
```

This is because the ownership of the object is then managed by Qt itself.
There are many cases for which Qt takes ownership (by reparenting it if necessary) of an object, for instance when adding a widget to a layout and then setting the layout to another widget.

Comment: Your answer is **very useful** for me and I will adjust the position of `self.hook = None` before `self.setup_subUI()` to prevent rewriting.